# trigger code after certain number of clicks in vba

Tags: excel, vba

I am working in VBA on an excel userform. What I am trying to accomplish is I have a series of textboxes that will fill in various cells in excel. Once the user clicks on the command button called "Submit", a message box(using the "vbOkOnly") appears asking the user to verify the information on the form prior to submitting information. After the user clicks "OK" on the messagebox it returns back to the userform. If all the information is correct the user clicks on the "Submit" button a second time at which time the information will be placed into the appropriate cells. So I would like to count the number of clicks of the "Submit" button and after two clicks execute a line of code. I found the following code below online. Is there anyway to build off/alter the code below to do what I want?

```
    Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Static cnt As Long
         cnt = cnt + 1
         Me.Label1.Caption = cnt & " " & "Click(s)"

    End Sub
```

In the space below Me.Label1.caption = cnt & " " & "Click(s)" I would like to add the following line of code to test the counting of the CommandButton1 clicks. If the number of clicks equals two, execute the messagebox.

```
If cnt = 2 Then
        msgbox("Please review Content",vbOKOnly,"Please review content")
End If
```

The first problem I need resolved is that I get a "Compile error: Syntax error". Not sure where I went wrong on this code. It seems ok to me. The second issue would be executing the messagebox only after two clicks. Thank You.

Comment: It should be `msgbox "Please review Content",vbOKOnly,"Please review content"` Ie no ()

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you are looking for:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Static cnt As Long
cnt = cnt + 1
Me.Label1.Caption = cnt & " " & "Click(s)" 
'This line is not required, you can safely remove it unless you really want to show how many clicks have been done.
    If cnt = 1 Then 'after first click show msgbox
        MsgBox "Please review Content", vbOKOnly, "Please review content"
    Else 'if more than one click then Submit data and reset cnt back to 0
        'Code to Submit data to Cells
        cnt = 0 'reset counter
    End If
End Sub
```